# I want show Modal Bottom Sheet when I click the marker on Google Map Flutter

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

```
class Peta extends StatefulWidget {
    _PetaState createState() => _PetaState();}

class _PetaState extends State<Peta> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  void initState() {super.initState();}
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {_controller.complete(controller);}

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(title: Text("PETA"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],)
   body: Stack(children: <Widget>[_peta(context),])
  )
 }

 Widget _peta(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   child: GoogleMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated, mapType: MapType.normal,
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(-1.265386, 116.831200), zoom: 14),
    markers: {marker1, marker2},
   )
  );
 }
}

Marker marker1 = Marker(markerId: MarkerId("TOKO 1"), position: LatLng(-1.277025, 116.829049),
 infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "TOKO MAKMUR"),
 icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen,),
 onTap: () {
  showModalBottomSheet(
   context: context, /// this line is error
   builder: (builder){return Container(......)}
  );
 }
)
```

that is my code. i want to to show some detail of place that marked with bottom sheet. i don't know how to pass context into it. i've already tried some answer on similar question but i get trouble too with "onMarkerTapped" method. i've already too use other maps plugin, it's work but the quality of maps is bad. please help

Answer (score 1):

use context holder from pub packages
https://pub.dev/packages/context_holder

Answer (score 0):

Your Bottom Sheet modal should looks somethings like this:

```
void _showModal() {
    Future<void> future = showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
                child: Wrap(
                   children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                           leading: Icon(Icons.star),
                           title: Text("Favorite"),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                           leading: Icon(Icons.close),
                           title: Text("Cancel"),
                        ),
                  ],
            ),
        );
      },
    );
  future.then((void value) => _closeModal(value));
}

void _closeModal(void value) {

}
```

and then you can call it over your onTap gesture:

```
onTap: () {
   _showModal();
},
```

Comment: thank you very much, sir. I've already follow your code, but I got an error again when I call the method _showModal() in the Marker.

Comment: could you provide the error? do you have your _showModal(); method inside your Stateful Widget?

Comment: `Marker marker1 = Marker(`
`markerId: MarkerId("TOKO 1"),`
`position: LatLng(-1.277025, 116.829049),`
`infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "TOKO MAKMUR"),`
`onTap: () {`
`_showModal(); /// this line error`
`}, );`

yes, put it on. I put method _showModal() inside after method _onMapCreated(), and Marker too after widget _peta

Comment: could you upload you current stateful widget with this? or a screenshot with the error in that line. Normally the IDE will tell you which error you're getting.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know to formating code in this comment

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TSqG5eM.png
https://i.imgur.com/aUeXxPD.png
https://i.imgur.com/f8YWKKy.png

error in the last image

Comment: You're not showing the error... you need to point your mouse over the red underline in order to know the error.

Comment: add "static" before "void _showModal() {", would look like this: "static void _showModal() {" (in your line 22)

Comment: Thanks,sir.. but now the context get an error again, sir.. https://i.imgur.com/m1fZqCz.png

Comment: Your Marker is getting out of scope and that's why you can't call it. Maybe you can create a new call and call it from there.

Comment: I'm sorry, sir. if I don't understand.. but like as before everything I put inside statefulwidget, so where should I put the Marker and method to in of scope ?